# Is there a shortcut to keyframe an entire skeleton?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, keyframes, shortcut

I'm new to animation in blender and I'm trying to make some character animations for UE4. I was wondering if it were possible to keyframe every bone at once instead of having to hit 'I' over rotation for every bone in a new pose? It sure would save a lot of time.

Comment: You need to create a key set that contains the parameters you want to include for keyframing. https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html?highlight=key%20set

Answer (score 6):

In the timeline, activate the red record button to automatically insert a new keyframe every time you move a bone, and the "two keys icon" aside to use the selected option for keyframing; then select from the menu the "whole character" option to  keyframe all the bones of the character everytime you hit the "I" key.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In pose mode for the armature select all bones with the keystroke

[a]

then keystroke [i].  The menu will appear and you may choose the keyframe attributes.